# Reveal and conceal CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

So I have an animation that will reveal something, this is visible in a few places on my site.

However I am now trying to reveal and conceal a modal overlay.

[image: Modal Overlay]

This appears over the modal form when submitting, and disappears when the AJAX call returns some data.

The problem is that the animation gets stuck after 'concealing', which means I cannot click submit and have it 'reveal' again.

Before AJAX:

```
<div class="loadingElement animate-reveal" style="display:none;">...</div>
```

AJAX Start:

```
$(".loadingElement").show();
```

AJAX Success:

```
$(".loadingElement").removeClass("animate-reveal");
$(".loadingElement").addClass("animate-conceal");
```

If you want to take a look for yourself please go to:
http://halden.101test1.co.uk/college/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing the animate-reveal class from your element which is going to make it never animate again. Right where you do $('.loadingSignin').show(); you need to re-add that animate at the beginning of your ajax query.

Just toggle the two necessary classes which will all you to have the animation and display your element.

Where your AJAX begins add the following line:

```
$('.loadingSignin').toggleClass('animate-conceal').toggleClass('animate-reveal');
```

Here is what that starting block would be:

```
if (form.valid()) {
    $('.loadingSignin').toggleClass('animate-conceal').toggleClass('animate-reveal');
    $(".loadingSignin").show();
```

Then paste the exact same thing again where your ajax call is finished.

```
success: function (data) {
    // log data to the console so we can see
    console.log(data);
    $('.loadingSignin').toggleClass('animate-conceal').toggleClass('animate-reveal');
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't quite get this to work from just copy and pasting, maybe I didn't understand your answer too well but it definitely helped. All I had to do was change the overlay div's class to animate-conceal and then add the toggle function below form.valid() and after AJAX success. Thanks for the non hacky help! :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution but it feels somewhat hack-y, feel free to still weigh in.

AJAX Success:

```
$(".loadingSignin").addClass("animate-conceal");

$(".loadingSignin").one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", function () {
    $(".loadingSignin").hide();
    $(".loadingSignin").removeClass("animate-conceal");
    $(".loadingSignin").off("animationend webkitAnimationEnd");
});
```

Comment: See my answer for a non "hacky" way :)